# Wordpress Comments - Only show part of user name

Tags: comments

I have searched and cannot find anything regarding this.

What I want to do is only show part of the users logged in name or username when they leave a comment (it is actually a product review but it uses the comments system).

I need something like what eBay does where is shows something like a*******z.

Is there any code or settings I can change to achieve this?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use combination of `substr` and `str_repeat` PHP functions to achieve this. Although it's very simple.

```
<?php

    function hide_username( $username ) {
        $stringlen = strlen( $username );
        return substr( $username, 0, 1 ) . str_repeat( '*', $stringlen - 2 ) . substr( $username, $stringlen - 1, 1 );
    }

    $username = 'roberthue';
    echo hide_username( $username );

?>
```

Now if username is roberthue then it will print r*******e.

I was testing it and it's working as advertise. To use this on comment author names, You will have to modify your comment list function. I was using `twentytwelve` theme, it has `twentytwelve_comment` function to print comment list but it could be different for you if you are using custom or commercial theme. In your comment list function you will find `get_comment_author_link()` to print author name and link.

You can replace it with `get_comment_author_link()`.

```
hide_username ( get_comment_author() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dive into comment template in your theme and find out the line where username is printed. Then use the following function in functions.php:

```
function alter_username( $username ){
    return substr( $username, 0, 1 ). str_repeat( '*', strlen( $username ) - 2 ) . substr( $username, strlen( $username ) - 1 ,1 );
}
```

Then use the function in comment template or wherever you want to show altered username like:

```
echo alter_username( $username );
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to WordPress dashbord, and choose the right user and select the proper value of 'Display name publicly as' as your wish for every user. If there are a lot of users, simply modify your code from [the_author](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author)
to [the_author_meta('first_name')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta). Here you can change 'first_name' to something else as given in the function reference page.